# Lockscreen widget not available in widgets list on iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, swiftui

I've developed a lock screen widget for the Flutter application using SwiftUI. The widget is working on the iOS simulator. However, when I'm uploading the app to Test Flight and after installing an app to the real device try to add a widget to the lock screen but the widget is missing from the widgets list.

From my research I found below solution and tried still issue is not resolved.

> https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655393
>
> As per the release notes, you need to set "Dead Code Stripping" to NO
> in your extension target's build settings. This is only necessary for
> the extension's target. When uploading your archive to the App Store
> Connect, uncheck "Include bitcode for iOS content".

[image]

Am I missing something? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had a some problem but fortunately I've realized that I'm using a `WidgetBundle` and after including the new widget in that bundle, it was available in the list.

Update: here's a source code for the bundle:

```
@main
struct MyWidgets: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        AWidget()
        BWidget()
        
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *) {
            LockScreenWidget()
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially if you have multiple widgets, they need to be included in a bundle.

Comment: Could you please add a code snippet for better understanding?

Comment: tried this solution but it's not working for me.